# Using data attribute with :first-of-type:before not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, attributes

this is my css:

```
.row[data-section='2']:first-of-type:before{
    content:"Sector 2";
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

this is my HTML:

```
<div class="pm-main-viewport-inner">
    <div class="row pm-sortable-row-ctn animated bounceIn ui-resizable" data-section="1">
        <div class="pm-section-overlay selected" style="display: block; opacity: 0.6; background-color: rgb(3, 14, 222);"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pm-sortable-row-ctn animated bounceIn ui-resizable" data-section="2">
        <div class="pm-section-overlay selected" style="display: block; opacity: 0.6; background-color: rgb(3, 14, 222);"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pm-sortable-row-ctn animated bounceIn ui-resizable" data-section="2">
        <div class="pm-section-overlay selected" style="display: block; opacity: 0.6; background-color: rgb(3, 14, 222);"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    </div>                
</div>
```

But is putting the before element on the first .row irregardless of the [data-sector], its like its ignoring the [data-sector='2']

Comment: without HTML code we cannot answer

Comment: @Temani Added the HTML